# Github project pages

Tags: github

I have the below repository;

https://github.com/garfieldmoore/mychesscalculator/settings

I have configured github pages to point to mychessgrade.com

I have configured A records for the below;

@ 192.30.252.154
@ 192.30.252.153

www 192.30.252.154
www 192.30.252.154

However, when I browse to mychessgrade.com the browser reports the below error;

mychessgrade.com redirected you too many times

I've done this for my user pages and it's worked.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't a problem after all - it was my DNS TTL that was confusing me.